# Sort / display recent posts by publish date

Tags: date, publish, recent-posts

I recently renovated some sites and made many small (usually typos) corrections to several posts. That of course changed the last update date, so that now, if I display recent posts in a widget, they are sorted in a totally useless way. The best sort order would be by publish date, but I don't see such option anywhere.

Is it possible to display recent posts by publish date instead of update date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Recent Posts widget, and the posts page for that matter, doesn't display ordered by update date, it orders by published date. If it's displaying by updated date then you must have a plugin somewhere that's changing this behaviour, or are using something other than the standard Recent Posts widget.

Comment: That's why I could not find any question on the topic;)